# Update object inside a list Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to modify my `allVehicles` variable, so it should contain the `problem` information that's in the `vehiclesWithProblems` list.

This is a simplified version of my code, but I need an updated `allVehicles` list that contains the `replacement` and remove the old one (the one without the `problem`).

How could I achieve that? This code is not working, the `allVehicles` list remains unchanged.

```
data class VehicleContainer(
        val id: Int,
        val vehicles: List<Vehicle>
)

data class Vehicle(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val problem: Problem
)

data class Problem(
        val quantity: Int,
        val problemList: List<Int>,
        val info: String? = ""
)

fun main() {
    val vehiclesWithProblems = listOf<Vehicle>() //list of vehicles with problems - wont be empty
    val allVehicles = mutableListOf<Vehicle>()//list of all vehicles (initially without any problems, but won't be empty either)

    allVehicles.forEachIndexed { index, vehicle ->
        val newVehicle = vehiclesWithProblems.find { vehicleWithProblem -> vehicle.id == vehicleWithProblem.id }
        if (newVehicle != null) {
            val replacement = vehicle.copy(problem = Problem(
                    quantity = newVehicle.problem.quantity,
                    problemList = newVehicle.problem.problemList,
                    info = newVehicle.problem.info)
            )
            allVehicles[index] = replacement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? What is not working?

Comment: the allVehicles list remains unchanged. I'll edit the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me the allVehicles list is actually modified, but beware! You make a copy of the vehicle where only the problem is changed, the rest remains unchanged. Runn the underneath code and you will see that after looping, the «Tesla without a problem» is still in the list, but now with a problem (so the list actually *is* changed.):

```
fun main() {
    val vehiclesWithProblems = listOf(Vehicle(1, "Tesla", Problem(1, listOf(1), "Problem #1"))) //list of vehicles with problems - wont be empty
    val allVehicles = mutableListOf(Vehicle(1, "Tesla without a problem", Problem(0, listOf(0), "No problem")))//list of all vehicles (initially without any problems, but won't be empty either)

    println("vehiclesWithProblems: $vehiclesWithProblems")
    println("allVehicles: $allVehicles")

    allVehicles.forEachIndexed { index, vehicle ->
        val newVehicle = vehiclesWithProblems.find { vehicleWithProblem -> vehicle.id == vehicleWithProblem.id }
        if (newVehicle != null) {
            val replacement = vehicle.copy(problem = Problem(
                    quantity = newVehicle.problem.quantity,
                    problemList = newVehicle.problem.problemList,
                    info = newVehicle.problem.info)
            )
            println("Changing #$index!")
            allVehicles[index] = replacement
        }
    }

    println("After the loop, allVehicles: $allVehicles")
}
```

Comment: the problem was in my actual code, I used newVehicle.copy instead of vehicle.copy. But thanks to you I realized. Thank you so much!!